# Php and shadowbox

Tags: php, lightbox, shadowbox

I have the form script

```
    <form action="grava.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="linkfoto" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao']=="cadastrar"){echo $src;}?>" />
    Matricula: <input type="text" name="idfunc" /><br />
    Nome: <input type="text" name="nomefunc" /><br />
     <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

And i want to send form info for grava.php on shadowbox and make a script on grava.php to close the box few seconds after open.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(window.parent.Shadowbox.close, 10000); // 10 seconds delay
```

Comment: but how to submit form content on shadowbox when i click on submit button?